# Prove $A \cap B \subseteq A $

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I am learning from Apostle's Calculus Vol.1 and could really do with some verification.

Question 12(sect. 12.5): prove $A \cap B \subseteq A $

Proof: Let $x \in A \cap B$ if $x \in A$ and $x \in B$. Thus, $A \cap B \subseteq A $ if $A \subseteq B$ or $A \subset B$

Comment: I'm lost after your "Thus".

Comment: More simply : $x \in A \cap B \text { iff } x \in A \text { and } x \in B$. Thus, $(x \in A \cap B) \to (x \in B)$ and this is simply the def of $\subseteq$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first sentence introduces an element $x$, which is not mentioned in the second one. It doesn't make sense.

Simply say that if $x\in A\cap B$, then, by the definition of $A\cap B$, $x\in A$. Since thus occurs for each $x\in A$, $A\cap B\subseteq A$.

Comment: Reading the question I get the impression that $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ might be distinct notions for the OP. So to avoid confusion I think it is better to write $A\cap B\subseteq A$.

Comment: @drhab Your are right.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it has clarified some things for me.

Comment: It should be "Since this occurs for each $x\in A\cap B$".